# Polymer 2.0 firebase-query not working with a dom-repeat template

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, polymer, polymer-2.x

I have problems with this dom-repeat template:

```
<firebase-query
 id="query"
 app-name="guiameDB"
 path="/MerloSL/farms"
 data="{{data}}">
</firebase-query>

  <template is="dom-repeat" items="[[data]]">
    <p>[[data.$key.nomb]]</p>
  </template>
```

The firebase node in farms is just like this object that I threw to console:

```
(7) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
$key : "0"
coment : "A metros de esquina con Comechingones"
dire : "Los Huarpes 88"
nomb : "Los Huarpes"
tel: "+5402656 475462"
turno: "Lunes"
__proto__ : Object 
1 : $key:"1"
coment : "Fr..."
etc...
```

If I put a 0 or a 1,2 etc. instead of the $key variable, it works, but with only one item, of course.
Any idea on this? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to put `$key`. 
Change your `dom-repeat` code to:

```
<template is="dom-repeat" items="[[data]]">
    <p>[[data.nomb]]</p>
</template>
```

Comment: Thanks Ofisora, I already tried that way and it did'n work.  It seems like `data.nomb` don't exist but `data."some id".nomb` exist, and I don't know how to drill at that level.